# macOS 13.1 launchd job fails with OS_REASON_CODESIGNING

Tags: macos, launchd, code-signing

I have mongod running in the background, installed through homebrew. I've updated to macOS 13.1 yesterday and now mongod fails to start. The launchd sys log shows the following error:

```
2022-12-14 09:50:42.208654 <Notice> xpcproxy exited due to OS_REASON_CODESIGNING | Launch Constraint Violation, error info: c[5]p[1]m[5]e[5], (cdhash) launch type 0, failure proc [vc: 0]: /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/5.0.4/bin/mongod
2022-12-14 09:50:42.208663 <Warning> removing service since it exited with consistent failure - OS_REASON_CODESIGNING | Launch Constraint Violation, error info: c[5]p[1]m[5]e[5], (cdhash) launch type 0, failure proc [vc: 0]: /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/5.0.4/bin/mongod
2022-12-14 09:50:42.208666 <Notice> exited with exit reason (namespace: 3 code: 0x4) - OS_REASON_CODESIGNING | Launch Constraint Violation, error info: c[5]p[1]m[5]e[5], (cdhash) launch type 0, failure proc [vc: 0]: /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/5.0.4/bin/mongod
```

Running the command manually works fine, so it is a problem with launchd trying to run the command. How can I 'sign' the binary that I've installed a long time ago?

Answer (score 0):

)I am having a similar issue (in my case the bacula-fd service - similarly installed via homebrew).  I think the canonical method is to use the codesign utility, however, when attempting to verify the signature I get the following:

```
codesign --verify --verbose /usr/local/Cellar/bacula-fd/13.0.1/bin/bacula-fd
```

result:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/bacula-fd/13.0.1/bin/bacula-fd: valid on disk
/usr/local/Cellar/bacula-fd/13.0.1/bin/bacula-fd: satisfies its Designated Requirement
```

So it's seems likely this is a regression or else not what it appears to be.  Hopefully this helps.