# Mac 13 application crashes only during reboot but has no issues manually launching launchctl

Tags: macos, startup, gatekeeper

My app is code signed. The package is notarized using `altool` and stapled. Only thing is my app is notarized but still not stapled dont know why, even though package is stapled validated through stapler validate.

When I launch it in normal user session no errors. It only happens at boot time and the error in `launchd.log` gives

```
xpcproxy exited due to OS_REASON_CODESIGNING | Launch Constraint Violation, error info: c[5]p[1]m[1]e[0].
```

I validated using `codesign -vvv --deep --verify` that my app is properly signed. Also it never crashes no matter how many times I launch it using launchctl.

I see many other apps like `tailscale` and others facing [same problem](https://github.com/tailscale/tailscale/issues/7460) but fixing it using ad-hoc signing. I cannot do that. Any help will be highly appreciated. TIA

A similar issue has been seen by others but no solution was provided there in [macOS 13.1 launchd job fails with OS_REASON_CODESIGNING](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/451892/macos-13-1-launchd-job-fails-with-os-reason-codesigning)